# Regarding structures in C

Tags: c

If I try to run this code then it doesn't ask me the value of `s2.name`. Why is it so?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
         char name;
         int roll;
         int age;
    };

    struct student s1;
    struct student s2;

    printf("Enter name of the student: ");
    scanf("%c", &s1.name);
    printf("%c", s1.name);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter name of the student: ");
    scanf("%c", &s2.name);
    printf("%c", s2.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` only holds a single character.  You probably want a string for `name`.

Comment: I am only typing one character then too the same is happening.

Comment: and to read a string, ue `scanf("%s", s1.name);` and declare name as `char name[20];`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but i want to read a character for this program.

Comment: If you type in something that's longer than a single character, i.e. a string, then the `scanf("%c", &s1.name)` only reads in the first character and the rest remains in the keyboard buffer (stdin). Then, `scanf("%c", &s2.name);` will take the first character it gets, that is in stdin.

Comment: I am not doing that. Please, run the code yourself. I am writing only one character. Then too there is an issue.

Comment: "I am writing only one character."  --> Are your typing the <Enter> key?  That is a character too.

Answer (score 2):

When you input a single character and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you are actually inputting *two* characters: The character in your input and a newline from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The second `scanf` reads this newline.

Or if you give multiple characters as input to the first name, then the second character will be read by the second `scanf`.

---

The way to solve the first problem is easy: Tell `scanf` to read and discard *leading* white-space (which newline is) by adding a single space in front of the format, like

```
scanf(" %c", &s2.name);
//     ^
// Note space here
```

The way to solve the second problem is to read *strings* instead, which means you have to turn your `name` members into arrays and then use the `"%s"` format (preferably with a specified width so you don't read to many characters).

Comment: I am not doing that. Please, run the code yourself. If it goes fine with yours then there may be some problem with my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically inputting two characters: 

 - the one that you type
 - the newline character `\n` because you hit `enter`
A solution to this problem is clearing stdin after reading in the first "name":

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
         char name;
         int roll;
         int age;
    };

    struct student s1;
    struct student s2;

    printf("Enter name of the student: ");
    scanf("%c", &s1.name);
    printf("%c", s1.name);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdin); //only works on windows, clears the input buffer
    printf("Enter name of the student: ");
    scanf("%c", &s2.name);
    printf("%c", s2.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Another way to clear the input buffer is:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

This reads in all characters from the input buffer, because as soon as input is read by functions like `getchar()` or `scanf()`, the input is removed from `stdin`.
**EDIT:**
When you input values using `getchar()`, `scanf()`, etc., then the symbols that you type into `stdin` (most of the times via a keyboard) are stored in the input buffer at first (stdin). `getchar()` or any similar function then takes the values that it should read in, out of the input buffer. For example:

```
scanf("%d", &var);
scanf("%d", &var2);
```

If I input `5x`, the characters in the input buffer are `'5', 'x'` and `\n` (because you hit the `enter` key). The first `scanf()` then takes out the `'5'`, as it fits the format string `%d`. After that, the characters in the input buffer are `'x'` and `\n`. In this case `scanf` returns `1`, because it read in one value correctly.
When it then continues to the second one, `scanf()` won't even let you type anything, as there is already something in the input buffer `stdin`. It won't store any data however, because the first "item" in `stdin` ist `'x'`. That doesn't fit the format string `%d`. The compiler then doesn't continue to read. In this case `scanf` would return `0`, as no value was read in correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps a lot. In other programs also the same issues were coming but now they are all solved.

Comment: What is input buffer can you explain it?